# RoleStore and Role management in Asp.NET Identity Without Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I am writing WCF Services, I authenticate User who will have access to my WCF Services through ASP.NET Identity without Entity Framework. Now I got an issue on Role Authorization. I am using custom way without Entity Framework so for it to achieve authentication I created User class and UserStore Class. And how could I authorize the role?

[Note:I have Role in Database table (ASPNetRoles and  ASPNetUserRoles) that can only access WCF Services and I know I have to decorate the method with principalpermission.]

namespace CalculatorService
{

```
public class IdentityValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        using (var userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore("data=source=pcb-sql01;initial catalog=InsitePCB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")))
        {
            var user = userManager.Find(UserName, Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var msg = string.Format("Unknown Username {0} or incorrect password {1}", UserName, Password);
                Trace.TraceWarning(msg);
                throw new FaultException(msg);
                // //the client actually will receive MessageSecurityException. But if I throw MessageSecurityException, the runtime will give FaultException to client without clear message.
            }
        }

    }

}


public class RoleAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {

        using (var userStore = new UserStore("data source=pcb-sql01;initial catalog=InsitePCB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))
        {
            using (var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore))
            {
                var identity = operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity;
                var user = userManager.FindByName(identity.Name);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var msg = string.Format("Unknown Username {0} .", user.UserName);
                    Trace.TraceWarning(msg);
                    throw new FaultException(msg);
                }

                //Assign roles to the Principal property for runtime to match with PrincipalPermissionAttributes decorated on the service operation.
                var roleNames = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id).ToArray();//users without any role assigned should then call operations not decorated by PrincipalPermissionAttributes
                operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new GenericPrincipal(operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity, roleNames);

                return true;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}